# Google Forms discrepancy

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

When I add a list item to a Google Form I can set and get choices.

If I select a list item from an existing form I cannot.

```
items = form.getItems();

for (i=0;i<items.length;i++){
 Logger.log(items[i].getType());
 if (items[i].getTitle() == 'A List'){
    choices = items.getChoices();
 }
}
```

I can see the items are of type "List" in the log but getChoices throws an error

> TypeError: Cannot find function getChoices in object item....

Is this a bug in **Apps Script**? Is there something I can do to `cast` the item and make sure it is of the right type?

Thanks

Jeremy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reffer to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item). As you can see an item does not have a `.getChoices()` method. This method is available in specific types of items, like [ListItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item). So you need to specifically do something like

```
choices = items[i].asListItem().getChoices()
```

Remember that `items` is an array and you need to specify which item you are getting choices for. You then need to specify what type of item it is (i.e. a list item) and only then you can get the choices. If this is something you need to do for **any** type of item, then you will need to figure out how to check what kind of item it is and then get it as that item type.

Comment: Aha! Thank you. That helped a great deal. The array part is okay.